# Mob Spawning/Despawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I've been building up my Villager Trading farms and halls and breeders, etc., and one of these builds is the converter - Using a zombie to convert the villager and back again to reduce trade costs.

I found a Zombie, and it can hold items which (should) mean that it won't de-spawn. I also gave it a helmet so that I could keep it in a boat while I build/if I need to save it from the sun.

However, when I came back to check on it, the zombie was still in the boat, still holding the item, but the helm had gone, and he burned in the sun.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Geared_zombies)

> Helmets (not blocks like pumpkins) on zombies can eventually wear away and break if the zombie is exposed to daylight.

Rephrased, if a zombie is wearing a helmet and is exposed to the sun, the helmet will lose durability until it breaks and allows the zombie to burn. This is a deliberate feature.

Comment: Today I Learned... now I can go to bed!

Comment: So yes, make sure to only rely on the helmet for short gaps of time, always give your pet zombie a shady place to hang out in.

Comment: It's always a good idea to have a roof for a village trading farm anyways, because if a lightning bolt hits a villager they become a Witch, which may or may not despawn.